# Segment image into windows in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using the following decision tree for detecting ROIs in an image: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3097782/figure/F7/. The first part uses a 32x32 window to scan the entire image using the code shown below. Can anyone tell me how to calculate the average intensity of the pixels within this window? Thanks

```
N = 32;
info = repmat(struct, ceil(size(M, 1) / N), ceil(size(M, 2) / N));
for row = 1:N:size(M, 1)%loop through each pixel in the image matrix
    for col = 1:N:size(M, 2)
        r = (row - 1) / N + 1;
        c = (col - 1) / N + 1;

        imgWindow = M(row:min(end,row+N-1), col:min(end,col+N-1));
        largest = max(imgWindow(:));
        [rLarg, cLarg] = find(imgWindow == largest, 1, 'first');

        window(r, c).largest = largest;
        window(r, c).row = rLarg + row - 1;
        window(r, c).col = cLarg + col - 1;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) function computes averages

```
average = mean(imgWindow(:));
```

You can then save each window average in a similar fashion to what you already did for the window maximum:

```
window(r, c).average = average;
```

Comment: Thanks. Should this not return a number of averages for each window? I am only getting one average.

Comment: What do you mean by a number of averages? The code written here will indeed return one average over all pixels in the window, similar to the way `max(imgWindow(:))` returns the single maximal value of all pixels in the window.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me how to get the mean for each window ?

Comment: Thanks. Though when I display this it is still only returning one average

Comment: What are you displaying?

Comment: i have tried both, display(average); and display(window(r, c).average);

Comment: If you place the `display` call inside the loop, it will display a value for each window. If you place it after the loop it will display the value for the last window.